# Google search result does not display my product price correctly

Tags: e-commerce, schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I have problem with Google search result. I have product page and they do not display the price correctly.

I've tried to make them crawl the page again and again.

I have put the correct price in the JSON-LD.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
[
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "Wishbone (Y) Chair - Oak - Natural Cord",
    "description": "<table class=\"no-border\">\r\n<tbody>\r\n<tr>\r\n<td style=\"border: none;\">\r\n<ul>\r\n<li style=\"text-align: left;\"><strong>Frame:</strong> Wood Painted Color, Beeach/ Ash/ Oak/ Walnut/ Maple</li>\r\n<li style=\"text-align: left;\"><strong>Legs</strong>: Wood Base</li>\r\n<li style=\"text-align: left;\"><strong>Fabric</strong>: Paper Cord</li>\r\n<li style=\"text-align: left;\"><strong>Warranty</strong>: 5 Years</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n</td>\r\n<td style=\"border: none;\">\r\n<ul>\r\n<li style=\"text-align: left;\"><strong>Assembly</strong>: Fully</li>\r\n<li style=\"text-align: left;\"><strong>Instructions</strong>: N/A</li>\r\n<li style=\"text-align: left;\"><strong>Clean</strong>: Dust /&nbsp; Spot Clean</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n</td>\r\n</tr>\r\n</tbody>\r\n</table>",
    "image": "https://www.zzz.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/image/265x265/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/h/f/hftuj.jpg",
    "offers": {
      "@type": "http://schema.org/Offer",
      "price": "299.0000",
      "url": "https://www.zzz.com/en/oak-natural-replica-wishbone-y-chair-hans-wegner",
      "priceCurrency": "GBP",
      "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock"
    },
    "sku": "XS-W03-SD006-Natural"
  },
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "speakable": {
      "@type": "SpeakableSpecification",
      "cssSelector": [
        ".description"
      ],
      "xpath": [
        "/html/head/title"
      ]
    }
  }
]
</script>
```

The expected price is £299. However it keeping saying that price is 119£ on the search result.

Comment: Was it 119 before? If you open the version from the Google cache, does it say 119 anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a canonical/duplicate issue. I looked at the cache for the example page:

/en/oak-natural-replica-wishbone-y-chair-hans-wegner

And it indicated it had been canonicalised to this page:

/en/black-replica-wishbone-y-chair-hans-wegner-natural-cord

Which has the 119 price.

Google is thinking that they are pages about the same thing, so merging them into one (canonicalising).

Product content duplication and canonicalisation is a well known issue, and not an easy one to resolve. There's lots of articles out there on it that may help.

You have a different URL for every variant of this chair. The only difference in content is one or two words mentioning colour or material. You may want to merge/consolidate them all into the one product/url making one strong and indexed page. Then mark up a price range.

Comment: I didn't spot that. Yes, those two lines will be sending very confusing signals to bots. Only have one canonical tag, and make sure it is right.